# RDS Serverless - Could not verify and start postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In the last few days, I'm having this weird issue with my Serverless Postgres RDS.
After deploying new code to the backend service the RDS server becomes unavailable, the only logs I could find are those :

[image]

Freeable Memory (MB):
[image]

The only document I found is [this one](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=927965), which said AWS working on fixing this issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The Unable to find the shared memory value, somehow seems to be related to the memory allocation issue. I don't think the link you shared is co-related to this. Can you provide more context with the memory used?

Comment: @NagarajTantri update with relevant

Comment: is there a way for you to increase the memory allocation and try the same? Also, It would be good if the error timestamp is shown in the first image, i.e. `7:56:23 AM` correlates with the timing of RAM usage.

Comment: yes, i increased the memory and it looks fine now. but why is it happening? what's the root cause? and why the servelress doesn't increase automatically ?

Comment: Glad that worked! The answer to that can be seen in their [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-working-with-amazon-aurora-serverless/#aws-comment-trigger-12173:~:text=Minimum%20capacity,-Capacity): _finding a scaling point can take time_ and _If there is a sudden spike in requests, you can overwhelm the database. RDS Serverless might not be able to find a scaling point and scale quickly enough due to a shortage of resources._

Comment: @NagarajTantri please post the last comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [AWS Blog on RDS serverless best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-working-with-amazon-aurora-serverless/#aws-comment-trigger-12173:%7E:text=Minimum%20capacity,-Capacity):

*Aurora Serverless scales up when capacity constraints are seen in CPU or connections. However, finding a scaling point can take time (see the Scale-blocking operations section). If there is a sudden spike in requests, you can overwhelm the database. Aurora Serverless might not be able to find a scaling point and scale quickly enough due to a shortage of resources.*

The error - `Error restarting database: Unable to find shared memory value in the  postgres.log file from pg_ctl getSharedMemory command` ideally would replace to memory allocation issue.

**The best way to handle it would be to keep a buffer/minimum higher allocation of memory while expecting a load on the server.**